# Why does returning from other web leave the last hash while showing the content of the first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

**Problem:** After I input a name and hit enter, the hash changes to 'pag2', showing different content. I click the red  link that goes to other website and, once I am on that website, I go back via back button in the browser. It still is www.luisalmerich.com#pag2, but shows the content from the empty location hash (the one you see entering directly).

If I have explained it badly:

*www.luisalmerich.com* **->** I input the text and hit enter **->**  *www.luisalmerich.com/#pag2* **->**  *www.siroppe.com* (red link on #pag2) **->**  Back button on browser **->**  *www.luisalmerich.com/#pag2* but with the content from www.luisalmerich.com

This is the web: http://www.luisalmerich.com/

My code isn't anything weird. Here is all the JavaScript the website has (it's probably causing the problem):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input1').keypress(function (e) {
       if(e.which == 13){
           location.hash="pag2";
       }
    });
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if (location.hash == "#pag2") {
        $('#pag1').css("display", "none");
        $('#pag2').css("display", "block");
        $('#pag3').css("display", "none");
    } else if (location.hash == "#pag3") {
        $('#pag1').css("display", "none");
        $('#pag2').css("display", "none");
        $('#pag3').css("display", "block");     
    } else {
        $('#pag1').css("display", "block");
        $('#pag2').css("display", "none");
        $('#pag3').css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

And here is the important html

```
<ul id="lista">
    <li id="pag1">
        <label id="label1" for="input1">
            Hola, soy Luis.<br/>
            Bienvenido a mi web personal.<br/>
            Antes de nada,<br/>
            ¿podrías indicarme tu nombre?<br/>
        </label>
        <input type='text' id="input1" autofocus autocomplete='off'/>
    </li>
    <li id="pag2">
        <label id="label2">
            <span id='nombre'>Buenos días X.</span>
            Me llamo Luis Almerich de Haro. Además de trabajar como creativo en la agencia <a href='http://siroppe.com/'>Siroppe</a>, estudio Publicidad y Relaciones Públicas en la universidad CEU de Valencia.</br>
            Nací hace 21 años en un pequeño pueblo de la costa gaditana y, desde que era un niño, me ha fascinado el mundo de la publicidad. También tengo otras pasiones como la tecnología, música, lectura, deporte y arte.</br>
            Me defino como una persona muy curiosa. Me encanta aprender cosas nuevas y, al igual que esta web, soy un lienzo en blanco en el que queda mucho por completar.</br>
            ¿Te interesaría saber algo más sobre mí?</br>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li id="pag3">
        <label id="label3">Voy a hablar un poco sobre mis cualidades. Tengo una actitud positiva hacia cualquier trabajo y gran facilidad para comunicarme y relacionarme con mis compañeros. Confianza en el trabajo, adaptabilidad dentro del entorno laboral y en el trabajo en equipo, auto-motivación y pasión en el entorno laboral.</br>También he participado en diversos voluntariados:<ul><li>Organización del festival de publicidad la Lluna 2014, a cargo de CSG Servicios.</li><li>Organización del cóctel de navidad del Colegio Publicitario 2014.</li><li>Miembro activo del Observatorio Beyond The Line desde Septiembre del 2014.</li><li>Colaborador de la marca Maru Cruz.</li></ul></br>Di mi gran paso al mundo laboral trabajando para <a href='http://www.estudihac.com/'>Estudi{H}ac</a> como New Business and Research.</p><p>Soy proactivo, me gusta participar en concursos, eventos y actividades. Durante el curso 2014/2015 participé en el concurso anual de publicidad Naranja Below, donde obtuve el segundo puesto. También participé en NASA Space Apps Challenge 2015, donde obtuve una mención especial por la mejor presentación y manera de vender un proyecto.</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Right now I'm not using pag3 because of this problem. Also, I know about the ASCII problems, I will fix them as soon as I can :)

**As you can see, nothing special. What am I doing wrong?** I just want to show the content of pag2 even when the user is returning from other web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(window).on('hashchange'` event is not actually firing when you come back from another site. The hash it's just there, since the beginning.

You will need to check for the hash in document.ready:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      if(window.location.hash) {
        // Fragment exists, do your staff to use it
      }
 );
```

Comment: :D 12 seconds faster, and my answer actually says nothing that yours is not. Gratz.